# FB.api doesn't bring profile name

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook JS sdk to show news feeds. the app works well for many users for for some users who have authorized my app doesn't bring reasonable result.

I use following code to get basic profile info which works for some users but for some it doesn't:

```
FB.api('/' + id + '?access_token=' + access_token, function (response) {
    var strTitle = response['first_name'] + "  " + response['last_name'];
});
```

In response object I receive only id, birth date, email, profile link but name is not available. Interestingly when I open profile link in my browser facebook says:

"Sorry, this page isn't available
The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

after that my code can bring its posts but again the from name of the posts is missing in response object. The permissions list is attached as picture.[image: Permissions list]

I can't understand what is going on and how can i fix this issue. Any help please?

Comment: Between the four "first_name", "last_name", "username" and "name" fields  when you request https://graph.facebook.com/THIS_USER_ID:
Question 1: Which field doesn't return at all?
Question 2: Which field return but with empty string?
Question 3: Do you able to visit https://www.facebook.com/THIS_USER_ID?
Question 4: If question 3's answer is 'yes', is her/his name is unicode?

Comment: Q1: none of you mentioned. i get only following data:
    {
       "id": "10000373602----",
       "link": "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=10000373602----",
       "birthday": "01/01/1980",
       "email": "some email",
       "timezone": -8,
       "locale": "en_US",
       "verified": true,
       "updated_time": "2012-11-24T07:01:34+0000"
    }
Q3: facebook.com/THIS_USER_ID returns:
"Sorry, this page isn't available The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

Q4: name is not unicode

Comment: How do you know the name is not unicode when you unable to visit www.facebook.com/THIS_USER_ID? Or another way, so you know the actual name, how you know this name?(because you say it's not unicode)

Comment: The application is in beta test yet and all the users are from USA so i am expecting it not unicode. The user registers on our website for other services too where his/her name is not unicode that's why I said so. BTW WHY graph says "Sorry, this page isn't availabl...." when i open facebook.com/10000373602----?

Comment: I mentioned about unicode because most of the people with unicode doesn't have username field. Like this guy https://graph.facebook.com/100003277574866. And i don't think account you mentioned is deactived or removed because you still able to access some info. I've no idea, may be some other people can help you :)

Comment: What do you think about this response: graph.facebook.com/100003736025182

Comment: Can you test the user access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token ? Normally you can see the user id and name at "User ID" field.(You can compare output from User Access Token which have the problem and those does't have the problem.)

Comment: And take a look at "Scope:" field. You should able to see list of permissions you granted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29356/discussion-between-salik-and-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the App center permissions feature (previously known for Authenticated referrals).

> Use these settings to enter the set of permissions your app requires when displayed in App Center

You should be passing a login url with the `scope` array of permissions in JS SDK.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

or via a login button

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_likes" data-show-faces="true" data-max-rows="3">Login with Facebook</div
```

Comment: I am already using the scope to give maximum permissions and after that having above problem. What do you think why is it working for some profile but not for others?